# If statement not working in my conditional ternary operator

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, select

I have the following if statement in PHP:

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo "<option " . $carDoors == $i ? "selected = 'selected'" : "" . " >" . $i ."</option>";
    } 

?>
```

I need the selectlist to be based on the value of `$carDoors` and if that's the case, I want to echo `selected = 'selected'`. At the moment I keep getting a fully empty selectbox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Um......... what "if" statement? the question lacks code, and a lot of it.

Comment: maybe ternary operator? pretty enigmatic post, any Alan Turing here?

Comment: $carDoors == $i ? "selected = 'selected'" : "", isn't it quite the same as an if statement?

Comment: That's conditional ternary operator. It has a different name (at least for PHP).

Comment: What is the value of `$carDoors`?  What is the output generated?  What is the expected output?  If I were to *guess* I imagine you could use some parentheses on that long line of code in order to explicitly define your order of operations, rather than assume the order.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code is, that the ternary operator `?:` has a higher precedence than the concatenation operator `.`. Your code is therefore evaluated as:

```
if ($carDoors == $i) {
    echo "<option selected = 'selected'";
} else {
    echo "<option  >" . $i ."</option>";
}
```

To get your desired output you should use brackets arround your short if:

```
echo "<option " . ($carDoors == $i ? "selected = 'selected'" : "") . " >" . $i ."</option>";
```

A list of operator precedence can be found [in the official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: @ndjsbj If this answer solved your problem please consider accepting it, so others can see that your problem was solved and find an answer more easily.

Comment: @ndjsbj (using the check mark to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `?` by this way:

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $selected = $carDoors == $i ? "selected = 'selected'" : "";
        echo "<option " .  $selected . " >" . $i ."</option>";
    } 

?>
```

or simple insert it into ():

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  echo "<option " .  ($carDoors == $i ? "selected = 'selected'" : "") . " >" . $i ."</option>";
}
```